# published npm package warning Fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, npm-publish

I published my first package using npm. However, when I import it in Codesandbox it gives me a warning

```
Error when converting '/node_modules/protected-react-routes-generators/src/index.js' esmodule to commonjs: Cannot read property 'type' of null
```

This is my [github Repo](https://github.com/MohammedSaberMohammed/protected-react-routes-generators)

Also when i installed it from NPM, it gives me this error
[image]

I don't know what this error is, any clue ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel can't compile jsx extensions. Install:

`npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`

And add to your .babelrc file:

`{"presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]}`

Comment: could you please  explain ? because i don't understand what do you mean by jsx extensions.
also i don't have `babelrc` should i write it in `package.json`

Comment: considering that i'm using CRA so how can edit babel configs

Comment: In your external packages (in `node_modules` folder), you have files with extension `.jsx` which is a syntaxic extension of javascript commonly used in React. But your javascript compiler (babel) can't natively handle this type of files. So you have to add some specifications to its configuration file which is `.babelrc` you can simply add at the same location of your package.json

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake which **I published the package as a react component without build it to be a raw javascript**